# Drawing a rectangle on a flex canvas is there a better way than 

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, geometry, canvas

To draw a "selection rectangle" from the mouse down , mouse move then remove it on mouse up i currently do the following:

My board is a canvas,
On mouse down i create a new UIcontainer i set his borders.
I update his width and height related the the mouse move position,
on mouse up i remove this child UIcontainer.

Do i have to create a new component for this kind of task or there is a better (lighter way) in flex ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [Flex selection rectangle](http://blog.jeethukarthik.com/flex-selection-rectangle/) example, although I think it won't be a better/lighter way, perhaps you can get some nice ideas from it.

Comment: This link is Broken :(

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you got it right.